# Dynamic Properties / Pivot Behavior in Azure CosmosDb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I try to simplify the output of a CosmosDb query. I'm using SQL / node.js SDK. I want to have objects, that are closer to the nature of JavaScript.

This is the result set I currently have:

```
[
    {
       "ts": 1557486186,
       "action": "first-login"
    },
    {
       "ts": 1575598533,
       "action": "last-login"
    }
]
```

It's the result of a group operation, and the *action* is hence a distinct value.

I want to have this:

```
[
  { "first-login": 1557486186 },
  { "last-login": 1575598533},
]
```

or this (even better):

```
{ 
  "first-login": 1557486186,
  "last-login": 1575598533
}
```

The set of property names is very limited and clearly defined.

Of course in JavaScript I can do this, but I really like the idea to have my DB delivering it as required.

#### Complete Clause

Just in case one asks, the SQL I use:

```
SELECT a.ts, a.action FROM (
    SELECT (c.action = 'login' ? 'last-login' : c.action) as action, Max(c._ts) as ts FROM c
    WHERE c.userId=12345 AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(['login', 'first-login'], c.action)
    GROUP BY c.action
) a
```

So, in the Db are one "first-login" and many "login" where I need the last one. But I think it's not relevant for the question itself.

So, how could `SELECT a.ts, a.action FROM` look like?

#### What I have tried so far

Not supported by Cosmosdb is the obvious approach, dynamic properties: `{ [prop]: value }`.
Any encapsulation in objects or arrays makes things worse. A zillion other variants result in syntax errors or other things with a **Bad request** outcome.

Comment: There's a [great article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/cosmosdb-materialized-views/real-time-view-cosomos-azure-functions/) on *materialized views* (using Cosmos DB + changefeed) that might offer a solution for you. At least, the intent is pretty much the same as what I think you're looking to achieve.